# How to set different Backend Layouts in TKET and pyQuil (Quil compiler)?

Tags: qiskit, programming, pyquil, pytket

In Qiskit it is possible to describe a CouplingMap on which a circuit get executed. This helps with testing different Layouts. There are many possibilities in Qiskit on how to do this. Firstly you can create a CouplingMapInstance and then create different shapes from methods (For Example a Line, Grid, Ring,.. Layout). Secondly you can draw circuits by 'hand' and just create a List of the Edges in the Layout.

However i do not find such things in TKet or pyQuil and my question is if I'm missing something here. All three do support Fully Connected Layouts.

I just googled again. It seems like pyQuil does support it in some way.
The QVM in pyquil offers the method get_qc() which returns a quantum machine. It is possible that you give '9q-square-qvm' as an input which returns a quantum machine with 9 Qubits on a square Layout.
Is there a way in pyQuil to customize a Layout like in qiskit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly I think you should look into TKET's architecture module.

https://cqcl.github.io/tket/pytket/api/architecture.html

You can for example define a `RingArch` or a `SquareGrid` architecture.

Maybe this jupyter notebook tutorial will be helpful to look at as well.
https://github.com/CQCL/pytket/blob/main/examples/mapping_example.ipynb